# Improving counter with animation AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

With what I’ve got now, which which is  “dynamic text” counting, how can I improve it with animation? I want “scrolling” like and odometer, and also want “ticking” like an LED.

**Parts I’m having problems with**
a. have the counter push array with different images “half understand this”
b. need animation to be a object I can change out “LED ticker, odometer scroller”
c. implementation "I'm confused"
[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/examp.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/examp.jpg)

```
//counter
var timer:Timer = new Timer(10);  
var count:int = 0; //start at -1 if you want the first decimal to be 0  
var fcount:int = 0; 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, incrementCounter);  
timer.start();  

function incrementCounter(event:TimerEvent) {  
  count++;  
  fcount=int(count*count/1000);//starts out slow... then speeds up 
  mytext.text = formatCount(fcount);
}

function formatCount(i:int):String { 
     var fraction:int = i % 100; 
     var whole:int = i / 100;  

    return ("0000000" + whole).substr(-7, 7) + "." + (fraction < 10 ? "0" + fraction : fraction); 
}
```

"Thanks for the help"

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/board2.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/board2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

http://shaneberry.net/numbers/

Comment: Yes. Can you post a link to that?

Comment: Rather than just post it, why don't you think about it a bit.  All I had to do to accomplish this vs. the one I already provided is modify the setTime function in NumbersView class.  Also, instead of having each number on one of ten frames, you want them all in another movieclip on the first frame, then move that moveieclip...

Comment: Ok, a moving symbol in a symbol. You adjusted setTime in numbers view. I figured there's more I need to learn.

Comment: I'm not being lazy, but I'm still trying to crack the first one. Embarrasing, but true. I know how Batman felt with the riddler. Sorry my brain went numb, but I'll be a worthy programmer six months from now if I survive this.